# How register a custom F# type with Npgsql?

Tags: f#, npgsql

I need to work around a [bug of F#](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/893), and need a way to use my custom type (a simple wrapper for decimal) but fail to see how do it:

```
open System.Data
open Npgsql
open Npgsql.TypeMapping
open NpgsqlTypes
open Npgsql.TypeHandlers.NumericHandlers

type money(value:decimal) =
    member this.value = value
    override this.ToString() = this.value.ToString()

let openConn(company:Option<string>) =
    let map = new NpgsqlTypeMappingBuilder(PgTypeName = "decimal",
                        NpgsqlDbType = System.Nullable<NpgsqlDbType.Numeric>,
                        DbTypes =  [| DbType.Decimal |],
                        ClrTypes = [| typeof<money> |],
                        InferredDbType = System.Nullable<DbType.Decimal> )

    NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.AddMapping(map.Build()) |> ignore        

    let conStr = localConnectionString()
    let conn = new NpgsqlConnection(conStr)
    conn.Open()

    conn
```

I get hit by:

> DataEngine.fs(73,73): Error FS0039: The type 'Numeric' is not defined.
>   (FS0039) (Server) DataEngine.fs(69,69): Error FS0039: The type
>   'Decimal' is not defined. (FS0039) (Server)

But the weird thing is that intellisense work here, and complete the type.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is the built-in money mapping to the built-in CLR decimal somehow not working for you?

Comment: I have a bug that happened with decimal (https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/893) and need to workaround it. I need to register my own "decimal" so the databases of my customers stop being corrupted.